# New state overwrite previous state

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

So I create a state of `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` but when I tried to add a new element, it's overwrite the all element. For example, at first I add a new element on the address value of 1, on the second time I add a new element on the address value of 9, but the all elements are overwritten with the new element (all the element of list, the address value is become 9). Do you guys ever have the same issue as I have? I'm stuck on this for several days

Before I add a new element:

[image]

After I add new element:

[image]

this is my code how I add the new element, the `state.values` is from a `BlocListener`, it's listen when a state is changed and carry the values

```
...
List<Map<String, dynamic>> _records = [];

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: ColorConst.appBarColor,
        title: Text(
          widget.field!.label!,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: BlocListener<ViewPageBloc, ViewPageState>(
            bloc: _formViewBloc,
            listener: (context, state) {
              if (state.isProcessing) {

                if (isSaveAndNew) {
                  _records.add(state.values);

                  _formViewBloc.add(ViewPageLoadFormModel(
                      modelName: (widget.field as RelationalField)
                          .relation!
                          .modelName));
                  isSaveAndNew = false;
                }
              }
            }
        .
        .
        .
        )
      )
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
```

Don't declare that on build methode. Your build methode is triggered twice.
Use instead ScaffoldMessenger().

```
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: ColorConst.appBarColor,
        title: Text(
          widget.field!.label!,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: BlocListener<ViewPageBloc, ViewPageState>(
            bloc: _formViewBloc,
            listener: (context, state) {
              if (state.isProcessing) {

                if (isSaveAndNew) {
                  _records.add(state.values);

                  _formViewBloc.add(ViewPageLoadFormModel(
                      modelName: (widget.field as RelationalField)
                          .relation!
                          .modelName));
                  isSaveAndNew = false;
                }
              }
            }
        .
        .
        .
        )
      )
    )
}
```

Comment: I've done it, but it still overwrite all the elements.

Answer (score 0):

So I recently had the exact same problem in a different context, that state kept overwritten with the last one. My problem was me thinking it was taking a copy of the list I was adding to a list of widgets. Instead, I had to make a new list from my local one that I kept adding to the global list.

```
List.from(tempList)
```

So an example of this would be:

```
 List<Widget> columnWidgets = [];

  void makeListWidgets()
  {
    List<Widget> temp  = [];

    for(var j = 0; j < nCols)
    {
      for(var i = 0; i < nCells; i++)
        temp.add(Text("$nCells"));
      columnWidgets.add(Column(children: new List.from(temp)));
      temp.clear();
    }
  }
```

Probably you already solved this one way or another, but I have found a few similar questions without an answer.